# LWC tests without Salesforce DX project structure

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

Is there any way to test LightingWebComponent in the salesforce project which doesn't has a DX project structure? In the documentation we can see that sfdx-lwc-jest works in Salesforce DX projects only. Did someone manage to test LWC well without using sfdx-lwc-jest ?

Comment: Why do you need this? What's wrong with using the DX structure?

Comment: We got old project which can't be rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you're outside of the Salesforce DX project structure you'll have to use the base LWC Jest packages and roll your own Jest setup. You can refer to the [LWC OSS doc](https://lwc.dev/guide/test) for basics of getting set up.

I think the biggest challenge here will be keeping the individual package versions up to date to match what is running in your Salesforce production org. For that you can try to stay in sync with what versions sfdx-lwc-jest is using:

https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/package.json#L25-L34

Something else to consider is you won't get the Lightning base component stubs for free. You'll need to keep those up to date and map to them in your Jest config via `moduleNameMapper`. Or create your own stubs as you go. Here are the stubs sfdx-lwc-jest uses:

https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/tree/master/src/lightning-stubs

Lastly, here's essentially the config sfdx-lwc-jest uses. For your project it's probably better to put this in a `jest.config.js` file rather than inlining it like sfdx-lwc-jest does.

https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/config.js#L21-L35